# Getting the list of list of combinations value from itertools

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

How can i obtain the list of list of combinations

```
 combi=list()
 for i in range(1,4):
    combi.append(list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3],i)))
  print(combi)
```

Results

```
[[(1,), (2,), (3,)], [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3)]]
```

desired output

```
[1],
[2],
[3],
[1,2],
[1,3],
[2,3],
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: .extend instead of .append?

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your issue.

```
import itertools

combi=list()
for i in range(1,4):
   combi += [list(ele) for ele in itertools.combinations([1,2,3],i)]
print(combi)
```